# OpenGLRenderer flushing caches (mode 0)

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-asynctask

i have i problem that i don't know the cause, so when running my application after an asynctask call in POST i change activity and when the new Activity is setting the main content to the screen the app crashes with any log.

The activty chages code is written in onPostExecute method of asynctask and i've tried  to do this in another thread calling the runOnUIThread method from activity but isn't working.
the only log that I see:

```
03-10 12:03:20.312: I/MyHttpClient(3160): HTTPResponse received in [1210ms]
03-10 12:03:20.367: I/my.app.package.ActivationActivity(3160): SendActivation onPostExecute: ActivationResponse [my.app.result.json.with.SUCCESS:result.code]
03-10 12:03:25.398: D/OpenGLRenderer(3160): Flushing caches (mode 0)
```

EDIT: now i have changed some names of classes and objects but is the code that don't work for me

```
class MyAsincTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    private Exception exception;
    private Gson gson;

    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        if (exception != null) {
            //deleted log code here
        } else if (response != null) {
            // I manage the json response from the server
            try {
                // I manage the json response 
                // determining if the server call was SUCCESS or ERROR
                if (resultCode.equals(Constants.RESULT_ERROR)) {
                    //deleted log code here
                }else if (resultCode.equals(Constants.RESULT_SUCCESS)) {
                    launchRegistration(); // I enter Here and then crashes
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //deleted log code here
            }
            //deleted log code here
        } else {
            //deleted log code here
        }
    }

}

    protected void launchRegistration(){

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(mContext, ActivityToOpen.class);
            mIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_TO_OPEN_ACTIVITY);
            mIntent.putExtra(Constants.SOME_EXTRA,  extras);
            startActivity(mIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }); 
}
```

is inside other activity, and the asynctask class is inner in other activity class.  this code for me work on many recent device, with recdent hardware and recent version like 4.4 and 5 and 4.3, but the problem is happening in other devicewith 4.0 and 4.1 with less hardware resource.

Comment: can you please post your code

Comment: i've edited the question right now, the code form me work in many cases but don't work in some cases described up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`<activity android:name="com.example.Activity"
           android:excludeFromRecents="true"
           android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
           android:label="@string/wizard.welcome.title"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.NoDisplay" /> `
```

the error that I did, is in the manifest declaration, some activity has the theme "NoDisplay" that don't work in recent version of android, but works in previous versions. And for this I had an issue.
Thank